# Simple C# Node List function that supposed to add to the start of the list doesn't work as an external Static Void

Tags: c#, list

Hi guys I wrote literally the simplest code ever, I tried 2 things, I even copied from online, but I can't realize why it doesn't work...
this is my code:

```
 public static void insertToStart(Node<T> list, T toAdd)
    {
        list = new Node<T>(toAdd, list);
    }
public static void insertToStart2(Node<T> list, T toAdd)
    {
        Node<T> list2 = new Node<T>(toAdd, list);
        list = list2;
    }
```

Both don't work and I have no clue why...
this is the main code:

```
Service<int>.insertToStart(list, 600); 
Service<int>.insertToStart2(list, 600);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this does not work is that you are attempting to assign a new `Node<T>` object to `list`, a parameter passed by value. Such modifications remain visible only in the method that does the modification, but have no effect on the variable passed as `list` in the caller.

You can fix this, for example, by requiring that `list` is passed by reference, i.e. marking `list` parameter a `ref`:

```
public static void insertToStart(ref Node<T> list, T toAdd)
{
    list = new Node<T>(toAdd, list);
}
```

However, this solution is not ideal. A better approach is to encapsulate `Node<T>` in a `NodeList<T>` class, and store the head as a private field so that you wouldn't need to pass `list` at all.

Comment: Thank it worked! but why? why can I add to the end, sort it, change it entirely without "ref", but here I must have that?

Comment: @NegevAsaf Strictly speaking, sorting and adding to the back do not work either: adding to the back would fail if the list is empty, and sorting would fail when the initial element needs to be moved. These "wrinkles" aside, the reason the other methods work is that `Node<T>` is a reference to a mutable object, and your methods modify properties of this object, without replacing the entire object with a new one.